# in wso2 identity server 5.1.0, locked user can still connect to management console. how to fix?

Tags: server, wso2, identity, locked

I installed wso2 identity server 5.1. I locked one user 'test1', but it can still connect to the management console ( I gave the user login privilege) even after a hour. does anyone know whether it is a configuration problem or a know issue to fix?
thanks 
Tony

Comment: How did you lock?

Comment: Have you lock following this guide https://docs.wso2.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=34612027

Comment: Hi, Bhathiya, I do followed the guide to lock or you cannot see the 'lock' check box in the management console.

Comment: if you need I can attach the screen copy of the the problem. it seems that I cannot upload the picture here.

Comment: i had to enable the account lock claim as described under Configure account locking claims¶ section under: https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/guides/identity-lifecycles/lock-account/